# Executable application with node.js

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to create an application (like a Windows executable) with visual interface using node.js?
Question arises because I was looking at an application (exe file in windows) which apparently runs javascript code and use a "web-style" presentation (probably encapsulating a Browser object) so controls look pretty much as a web application but running in a windows application.
Is there any known tool for this?

Thanks
Gus

Comment: Are you looking for Electron? https://electron.atom.io/ - it's used for programs like Slack and VS Code.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember the executable was signed as Electron, so it makes sense now. I tried to search for it without luck. I will look at your web address. Thanks